# Android - Alias for dimens.xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to get my android app to support multiple screen sizes. I'm trying to keep my alternative layouts to a minimum by changing the dp values of the layouts using different dimens.xml files.

The crappy part is that I have 9 different folders that contain dimens files (values, values-sw320dp, values-sw480dp, values-sw600dp, and values-sw720dp for higher apis, values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge for older apis) and I hate copy pasting from my sw values folders to the old values folders over and over.

I know how to create layout.xml file aliases [like this shows](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources), but does anyone know if you can do that for dimens files? I tried making multiple dimens files in my values.xml, but of course it doesn't work because then my two dimens files have properties with the same names, and that causes conflicts.

Can I maybe name my dimens file in `values-sw600dp` `dimens-large.xml` and reference it in the `values-large` folder?

Comment: This is something I have not tried, but most compilers and IDEs have a place to configure some custom build steps. Maybe you can create a little script that copies the files, and you add this script as a build step. Your script would be executed every time you build the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Merlevede's suggestion, and adding a script to eclipse's build path.

Specifically, select the android project, go to Project --> Properties --> Builders --> New

Make a "Program" builder, then select a file that is natively executable on your file system. Personally, I wrote a 3-line java app, jarred that, then wrote a batch file that just calls the java jar. The batch file is what I specified as the executable for the builder.

Then I put that builder to the top of the build list, and voila, my files are being automatically copied!

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically change size of layout components.
Here i am creating first xml layout according to 480*854 sized screen. Below code automatic fits UI according to screen size.

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getTheDisplay();
    getUiComponents();
    adjustUIComponents();

}private void getTheDisplay() {

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    width = dm.widthPixels;
    height = dm.heightPixels;

}private void adjustUIComponents() {
    // myButton is button from layout xml file
    adjustUI(myButton);

}private void adjustUI(View v) {
    //myButton is in LinearLayout
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = calculateWidth(211);//211 is width of button in px given in xml
    lp.height = calculateHeight(80);//80 is height of button in px given in xml

    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
}private int calculateWidth(int w) {
    int wi = (w * width) / 480;
    return wi;
}

private int calculateHeight(int h) {
    int hi = (h * height) / 854;
return hi;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, but I don't believe that's considered best practice, and it would still be pretty complex, while reducing my options for fine-grained control.